# Namespaced class is not autoloaded

Tags: php, php-5.3, spl, spl-autoload-register

I'm autloading my class in PHP with `spl_autoload_register`. This has been working fine for me so far. I have a site running on both Windows and a Linux server with no problems.

But now i'm trying to setup my framework on a different Linux server which gives problems when it needs to autoload ***certain*** classes.

This is what my class looks like:

```
<?php
namespace System\Helper;

class ADHelper
{
    // ... methods omitted for simplicity
}
?>
```

In my `index.php` I autoload classes like so:

```
function autoload_full_namespaced ( $class )
{
    $file = str_replace ( '\\', '/', $class );
    if ( file_exists ( $file . '.php' ) )
    {
        echo "a: " . $class . ' <br />';
        require_once ( $file . '.php' );
    }
}
```

When i load my site it displays all the classes that it autoloads:

```
a: System\Core\ADRegistry 
a: Bootstrap\ADConfig 
a: System\Database\PDO_Mysql 
a: System\Core\ADRouter 
a: System\Core\ADDispatcher 
a: System\Helper\ADHelper 
a: System\Core\ADPatcher\ADInterceptor
```

But it gives me an error about the `ADHelper` class, which seems to be `required_once`, since it is echo'ed.

> Fatal error: Class 'System\Helper\ADHelper' not found in
>   /home/vhosts/php/httpdocs/bday/System/Core/ADDispatcher.php
>   on line 121

Like i said before, it all runs fine on another Linux server (PHP 5.3.15) and on my Windows server (PHP 5.4.x), but **not** on the current Linux server (PHP 5.3.3).

I have no clue why it wouldn't work on this machine.

Anyone any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Did you check that all filenames are spelled correctly, and containing the corresponding classes?

Comment: @Hidde Yes i did. I even made sure that there are no differences in capitalization in both file, folder, namespace and class names.

Comment: Hints for debugging: Use absolute filenames, not relative ones as you just do. Use `require` instead of `require_once` as this is auto-loading. By the debug output the file containing the `ADHelper` class *is* required (at least once), however the definition seems missing. Using the non-once variant of `require` might uncover the underlying problem better.

Comment: @hakre In this case it shouldn't matter if i use relative or absolute fiilenames. `file_exists()` says that it finds the file. But non the less, i did give it a go resulting in the same error. Even tried `require()` instead of `require_once()`, but that didn't shed any new light either. I have a feeling this is just an issue with PHP 5.3.3 as it works perfectly in all other versions above that.

Comment: if `require` and using absolute paths give you the exact same error message, go into the file where the class you want to load is defined and throw an exception afterwards so that if the file is required your script comes to halt. If you can not see that exception message it's either not thrown (echo before so cover that) or it's swallowed (IIRC there was some changes/options about that). Just blaming the concrete PHP version might fit, however, I did understood you in the meaning that you want to find out why. So I'd say let's troubleshoot this to an end :D

Comment: Also did you try to debug this with a step-debugger like xdebug? It's often insightful to see how the code actually runs until such errors appear.

Comment: @hakre The source is on the server of a standard Linux web host. So unfortunately i can't use XDebug from there. Maybe i could install PHP 5.3.3 on my Windows machine and debug it from there (if the error even occurs on Windows), but it seems like i can't even download that version anymore: http://php.net/releases/index.php - Not for Windows or Linux.